# marquee text view animation

Tags: android

The marquee animation does not work, this is what I did.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bg_trans"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/trackName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"                
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:maxLines="2" android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
            android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/artistName" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"                
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:maxLines="2" android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
            android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

It works for the first textview but doens't work for the second. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me -

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/capture_mode"
android:layout_width="200px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
android:text="This is a test of marquee on the text view in android."
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
/>
```

The field `marqueeRepeatLimit` will set the number of repitions.

**UPDATE:** The width of the text view need to be hardcoded to a specific value, you can set it to `wrap_content`. In such cases the marquee will still work just that it will have some blank space after the end the text and before it starts to display the text again. (Think Digital signboards, they have some gap in the display before displaying the next item.)

Comment: but does the text have to be bigger than the textview for it to work?

Comment: well yes, otherwise I don't see the point in moving the text around since I can see the whole thing :)

Comment: well that's why I called it an animation

Comment: Hmm okay never thought that marquee can be used such cases as well. So to answer your question, no the text doesn't have to be bigger than the textview to work you can make the width of the textview as wrap_content and it will work. I will update my answer with this. Hope this is what you were asking for..

Comment: it works for teh first one but not for the 2nd one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you changed the question? I think this should be a new question besides I was hoping you would accept my answer to your original question. :)

Comment: anyway the reason is i think it only works cause only one thing can be in focus at a time...don't really know how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Other then what is mentioned above you also need to add

```
   txtView.setSelected(true)
```

worked for me adding this line